How to concatenate two Go 1.23 iter.Seq[E] together?
Go 1.23 comes with the new iter package and range-over-func feature.
Given two iterators, what's the correct way to combine them together?
import "slices"

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    b := []int{5, 6, 7, 8}

    i := slices.Values(a) // i is iter.Seq[int]
    j := slices.Values(b) // j is iter.Seq[int]

    // ???
}

The goal here is to iterate over both slices' elements in order, from 1 to 8. Apparently there isn't any ready-made helper in the slices package, is there?

True, the iter package provides no function for concatenating two iter.Seq[E], but you can implement one easily enough. Below is a Concat function (borrowed from my jub0bs/iterutil package) that takes a variadic parameter:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "iter"
    "slices"
)

// borrowed from https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jub0bs/iterutil#Concat
func Concat[E any](seqs ...iter.Seq[E]) iter.Seq[E] {
    return func(yield func(E) bool) {
        for _, seq := range seqs {
            for e := range seq {
                if !yield(e) {
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    b := []int{5, 6, 7, 8}

    for i := range Concat(slices.Values(a), slices.Values(b)) {
        fmt.Print(i, ",")
    }
}

Output:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,

(Playground)

No, the functions new in Go 1.23 are listed in “Range Over Function Types”
iter.Concat has been discussed and proposed. As long as there are issues open I would suggest using the code from Russ Cox:
// Concat returns an iterator over the concatenation of the sequences.
func Concat[V any](seqs ...iter.Seq[V]) iter.Seq[V] {
    return func(yield func(V) bool) {
        for _, seq := range seqs {
            for e := range seq {
                if !yield(e) {
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

or using a third party library. I'm sure this function will make it into golang.org/x/exp/xiter, but the package is still in planning.

This code looks identical to that in the other answer, no?

Sure. Russ Cox authored the first draft on Aug 9, 2023, jub0bs committed his first version on Sep 14, 2024. I assume there are not many ways to write such a trivial function, also jub0bs participated in the discussion where Russ Cox presented his suggestion. You mostly asked what the “the correct way” is, and I wanted to answer this by researching the current state and referring to the code I assume will land in golang.org/x/exp/xiter. Otherwise I'm sure you would have been able to write something very similar yourself.

Admittedly, I was not aware of xiter, haven’t followed the Go issue tracker for some time. It’s a useful mention, thanks

@eik Indeed, there are not many ways to write such a Concat function.
